# How can I get table row Id in selenium

Tags: c#, javascript, testing, selenium, guid

Currently, On page all control ids are dynamically generated. And in order to iterate through table, I need to get that row guid generated by java script.

e.g

```
<table id="tblPass" bgcolor="#ffffff" editmode="Full" style="width: 100%;">
<tr id="87425hdsfs98-38ad-48df-aa7b-j5jf94hs0l" class="passenger"> 
<td class="dragcolumn Adult pass">
<span class="PersonType"> Adult </span>
</td>
```

I need the id of a row so I may enter further information in columns based on that id. as All information for rows is same except for that id. Any idea how to get this id using selenium. please guide.

Update: I am using selenium RC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to find the element first, so something like:

```
var element = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("tr.passenger"));
var rowID = element.GetAttribute("id");
/* RowID would be "87425hdsfs98-38ad-48df-aa7b-j5jf94hs0l" */
```

You've edited to say you are using RC, which would be something like:

```
var id = selenium.GetAttribute("css=tr.passenger@id");
```

As for identifiying it in the first place, well you'll have to work outwards.

That is to say, if you want the parent `tr` in your example, use this XPath:

```
//span[text()='Adult']/ancestor::tr
```

That'll get you the element, then you query it for it's ID.

Comment: all rows have same class name as well. So how will I get the next row id

Comment: Many thanks. I tried your suggestion using Xpath and it worked brilliantly..cheers